# Expo av-player seamless gapless loop crossfade

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, avaudioplayer, avplayerlooper

Based on my experience and research, the out-of-the-box AV players for both Android and iOS do not fully support gapless/seamless looping. There is always a noticable gap when setting the isLooping=true on any of them. I have only been able to get this to seamlessly work on Android using the SoundPool, but that is only for small sound files, not large mp3's.

Currently, i wrote a solution that "semi-works" for iOS, but the weird thing is that it does not work on Android. I would guess they should at least be consistent?

Also, I'm interested if anyone could help solve this age-old problem of looping sounds in the most effective way possible where the user does not notice a gap. This cross fader idea is out of the box and maybe someone can help improve on it. I also opened a discussion on the expo forum and will update here if anything comes from there.

Here is the repo: https://github.com/happyruss/expo-fader-loop

Any suggestions on solving the issue would be awesome. It's also a fun simple project for someone trying out react-native/expo

Comment: Hi, we are using Expo-Av for the gapless Audio Player. While it works as charm in Android it doesn't in iOS. Did you have find any soluiton?

Comment: joining the party a little bit late but its 2023 - have you found a solution @ErenTüfekçi?

Comment: I implemented a naive seemless looper https://gist.github.com/smontlouis/d18fdce47c9003d1d24eecf9524eb97e#file-seemlesslooper-ts

Comment: @bulby97 that looks like the same approach i did where you are doing a crossfade, not a seamless loop. Crazy that's the best we got in 2023.